# Bing Map on ASP.Net webpage fails to render due to Razor Syntax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, bing-maps

I'm creating an navigation application using the Bing Maps REST Toolkit and ASP.Net MVC. However, whenever I run the Application, the map fails to render on the webpage, and there is nothing except a blank screen. I have deduced that this problem is something to do with the Razor syntax within the maps JavaScript that receives the location data, which is in these lines:

```
@if (Model.StopList != null){
   foreach(var StopLocation in Model.StopList){
       @:addNewWaypoint(@StopLocation.Name, @StopLocation.Geocode, directionsManager);
   }
}
```

I'm struggling to find what the specific problem is, and can't come up with any solutions or workarounds. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance, and my code is as follows:

**MapController.cs:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(){

            var Stops = new List<Stops> {
                new Stops (1, "Shelton Care", null , "ST4 7AA"),
                new Stops (2, "Stoke Station", null , "ST4 2AA"),
                new Stops (3, "Stop 1", null , "ST3 1TN"),
            };

            StopLists Model = new StopLists
            {
                StopList = Stops
            };

            var GeocodeList = new List<Task>();

            foreach (var StopLocation in Stops)
            {
                var gct = AddGeocode(StopLocation);
                GeocodeList.Add(gct);
            };

            await Task.WhenAll(GeocodeList);

            return View(Model);

        }
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@model FYP2._1.Models.StopLists
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div id="myMap" style='position:relative;width:600px;height:400px; top: 0px; left: 0px;'></div>
        <div id="itineraryContainer"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetMap() {

                var MapsKey = 'MyMapsKey';

                var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
                    credentials: MapsKey,
                    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(53.0146, -2.1864),
                    zoom: 17
                });

                var center = map.getCenter();

                getRoute(map);

                getTraffic(map)

            }

            function getRoute(map) {

                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function () {
                    var directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

                    //Set Route Mode to driving
                    directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving });

                    //iterates through locations and makes waypoints from them
                    @if (Model.StopList != null)
                    {
                        foreach(var StopLocation in Model.StopList)
                        {
                            @:addNewWaypoint(@StopLocation.Name, @StopLocation.Geocode, directionsManager);
                        }
                    }

                    // Shows where the written directions will be rendered
                    directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: '#itineraryContainer' });

                    directionsManager.calculateDirections();

               });
            }

            function addNewWaypoint(name, geocode, directionsManager) {
                var Stop = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
                    address: name,
                    location: geocode,
                });
                directionsManager.addWaypoint(Stop);
            }
```

Comment: Json is valid javascript, I find it easier to use serialisation to pass complex C# types to inline scripts. eg `var waypoints = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.StopList));`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is with the format of the geocode property of your stops. I recommend adding a break point in your addNewWaypoint function and verify that the geocode value is a location object. Also verify that the directionsManager exists there too.